# C# Extract Words Beginning with %! and Ending With !%

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract some words out of a paragraph of text if the word starts with **%!** and ends with **!%**

I'd imagine regex would be good for this but unfortunately my regex isn't that great...OK its pretty bad...OK its non existent :(.

**EXAMPLE TEXT**

```
You don't want no %!beef!%, boy
Know I run the streets, boy
Better follow me towards
Downtown
What you see is what you get %!girl!%
Don't ever forget girl
Ain't seen nothing yet until you're
%!Downtown!%
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
beef, girl, Downtown
```

How can I achieve this in C# with or without regex?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. There are many, many blog posts, tutorials and Q&As about substring matching.

Comment: Seems like a good time to learn regex...

Comment: You need to read [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970).

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments :) I looked at other questions on SO but I could find any that matched my question. Regexs are really useful but in my job unfortunately I don't get the opportunity to use them much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"%!(?<word>\w+)!%");
var inStr = @"You don't want no %!beef!%, boy
Know I run the streets, boy
Better follow me towards
Downtown
What you see is what you get %!girl!%
Don't ever forget girl
Ain't seen nothing yet until you're
%!Downtown!%";
var results = reg.Matches(inStr).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["word"].Value);
```

This will give you a list of matched words. Converting it to a comma-separated string is an exercise I'll leave up to you..

Also, next time you should probably do some quick research, you're eventually going to have to learn simple regexes..

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your advice. I don't use RegExs enough so its easy to forget how to use them!

Comment: @heymega go to http://regexone.com/ . This is one of the best sites to learn regex

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thank you - This is very useful.